# Linphone for iPhone is not receiving calls when it goes to the background mode

Tags: ios, background, linphone

I have integrated the `linphone` sdk in my app.When my app goes to the background mode, my app is not getting any incoming calls. I want to make work my app as like `skype` when it goes to the background mode.

I have added required background modes in info.plist.

```
  Application does not run in background  - NO
  Required background modes
    item 1        App provides Voice over IP services
```

I have implemented following method in `ApplicationDidEnterBackground` , still I'm facing same issue.

```
1.setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:
  [http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__IOS.html][1]
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not work in UDP mode, if your SIP server can be switched to TCP
mode it should work (eg: for asterisk use transport=tcp in your sip.conf).
It seems that IOS does not allow UDP traffic in background mode.

I recommend you to switch to SIP TCP/TLS for having background mode working on Linphone for IOS.

The only way to workaround this UDP problem is to force the iphone to stay live by creating a long running background task.
The result is that the device never suspends, which drains the battery very fast.

Comment: Is it working in background mode with TCP? I don't think so because even linphone appstore version or latest linphone open source project don't show anything for incoming calls once sent to background.

Comment: its working for me. I forcefully set transport as tcp on start up and set port as random port. i am getting call in background as well as when phone locked.

Comment: Hope you are talking about iOS version working in background not android version.

Comment: yes . i am talking about ios version. Even i mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: How to change the mode to TCP?

Comment: @GauravGupta you can change it from the account settings in Linphone.

Comment: @kaushikparmar where the account settings in Linphone?

Comment: I am using the Twilio SAAS SIP service and choose TLS on all devices. I added `transport=tls` to all Twilio TwiML messages. Linphone refuses to connect when running in the background. Same with Zoiper Lite. It works perfectly fine on Android. How do you people make this wok?